# how to insert multiple field data in one column in database in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I want to play with this fields,i want to insert description1,description2 data into this description[] how to do that i tried but something is missing.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="description" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Enter description">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="description" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Description 1 (optional)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description2" placeholder="Enter description">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="description" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Description 2 (optional)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description3" placeholder="Enter description">
    </div>
  </div>



     public function store(Request $request)
        {
$description1 = $request->input('description1');
        $description2 = $request->input('description2');
        $products = new ProductAdd;
            $prodduct->name = $request('name');
            $prodduct->description[] = [
                'description1' => $description1;
                'description2' => $description2;
        ];
            $product->save();
}
```

Comment: this is answer of my question i did it
                 $desc = [];
      $description = $request->input('description');
      $description1 = $request->input('description1');
      $description2 = $request->input('description2');
      
      $product = new ProductAdd;
      $product->product_name = $request->input('product_name');
      $desc[] = [
        'description'  => $description,
        'description1' => $description1,
        'description2' => $description2
      ];
      $product->description = json_encode($desc);
      $product->save();

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the `description` field to be an array in your model, you can update your controller code to:

```
$prodduct->description = [
    'description1' => $description1;
    'description2' => $description2;
];
```

To cast the field to an array, add this to your `ProductAdd` Model:

```
$casts = [
    'description' => 'array'
];
```